# modify default HAVE_POSTS() Loop without inserting new variable (i.e. $loop->HAVE_POSTS)

Tags: loop

i want to modify

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
```

the default way is:

```
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
```

but i dont want to insert a new $loop variable, but want to have still

`while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();`

with modified parameters. how to do that?

Comment: Search the site for `pre_get_posts`!

Comment: thank you! also, putting `<?php query_posts( 'post_type=bl');?>` above the `HAVE_POSTS()` helped me!

Comment: Search the site for `query_posts` and you will see that that is the wrong solution.